# Why does my emit work in only one direction?

Tags: javascript, eventemitter

I am using EventEmitter via a CDN script tag. I'm attempting to emit between an external script and a local script contained in the HTML script tag. Emitting from the external script works fine. But emitting from the HTML document script tag does not.

What am I missing?

HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EventEmitter/5.2.8/EventEmitter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="emitter.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script>
      e.on("fromJSFile", function(msg){
          console.log("Received message from external script: " + msg)
      })
      e.emit("fromHTMLScript", "Emitted from HTML script")
  </script>
</html>
```

External script (emitter.js):

```
let e = new EventEmitter()

e.emit("fromJSFile", "Emitted from external script")
e.on("fromHTMLScript", function(msg){
    console.log("Recieved message from HTML script: " + msg)
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to `emit` until all the handlers are added.  While I think emitting an event is supposed to occur outside of the current call stack, I'm not sure how they've implemented `setImmediate()` (etc.) in-browser.  There may be some implementation quirks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work both ways, but you need to wait for the listeners to be set before emitting.

Browsers will execute JavaScript as soon as it is parsed, so what will be executed is this (chronologically) :

```
let e = new EventEmitter()

e.emit("fromJSFile", "Emitted from external script") // An event will be emitted on "fromJSFile", but there are no listeners at the execution time
e.on("fromHTMLScript", function(msg){
  console.log("Recieved message from HTML script: " + msg)
}) // Adding a listener on "fromHTMLScript"


e.on("fromJSFile", function(msg){
  console.log("Received message from external script: " + msg)
}) // Adding a listener on "fromJSFile"
e.emit("fromHTMLScript", "Emitted from HTML script") // An event is emitted on "fromHTMLScript" and caught by the listener
```

What you need to do is setting up the listeners as soon as possible (you can set it up even before the page fully loads), and *then* emit with the page fully has fully loaded.

For example, you can write this in your JS file :

```
let e = new EventEmitter()

e.on("fromHTMLScript", (msg) => {
  console.log("Recieved message from HTML script: " + msg)
}) // Register listener on "fromHTMLScript"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  e.emit("fromJSFile", "Emitted from external script")
}); // Emit on "fromJSFile" when the page fully loaded
```

And this in your script tag :

```
e.on("fromJSFile", function(msg){
  console.log("Received message from external script: " + msg)
}) // Register listener on "fromJSFile"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  e.emit("fromHTMLScript", "Emitted from HTML script")
}); // Emit on "fromHTMLScript" when the page fully loaded
```

Comment: Would you mind showing an example of how to accomplish your suggestion using both the HTML script tag code and an external script? My use case requires it to work that way.

Comment: @Dshiz sorry for the late edit, I added a working code.

Comment: Interesting.. I was actually already trying to use this event listener, but not quite the way you implemented it. Much appreciated! It's also notable that I was able to work around this by adding my `script` tag containing the code on the HTML side to the `<body>` element and it is successfully working that way, too.